# Add name with space to personel hunspell dictionary

Tags: spelling

I am trying to add the name "de Gennes" to my personal dictionary.
I tried adding the expression as a new line to my dictionary, but unfortunately this seems not to work as both words get returned as mistakes.
I know I could add both words on seperate lines but would like to avoid that as they should only occur together. Is there any special escape character I need to use in my personal hunspell dictionary?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be TeX related.. Google search gives this, for eg. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7561648/8421052

Comment: Well, I use hunspell in my tex workflow to make nice documents, so I think it is somewhat related. Thanks for the link, but I already know how to create my own dictonary. I am only having difficulties with a whitespace character in my expression, which the post on SO does not address.